# How to preserve user uploaded content when pushing or pulling with git

Tags: node.js, git

I have a simple node application that lets a user upload photos that are stored in an `/uploads` directory.

My issue is that when I `fetch` or `pull` with git to grab the latest copy of the app, I also get the latest batch of files the user has uploaded. This is not an immediate problem, but if I were to `push` changes I made to the app, then the user's uploaded files will be overwritten or erased by whatever was in my local repo. If my local `/uploads` directory is empty, then so will be the same directory with the live app, even if it was empty before.

Is there a way with git to specify to only `pull` those user-generated files and  never `push` them?

Comment: These files shouldn't be tracked. Add all the uploaded files (or a folder- easier) to .gitignore file.

Comment: Put them in .gitignore then use usual ftp/http download for user-generated content. To make it seamless, you can create shell script that combine git pull and download command

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

- Remove the tracked upload files from source control

  ```
  git rm --cached -r ./uploads/
  git commit -m 'Removed uploads files from source control.'
  ```
- If you do not already have a `.gitignore` file in your project root, create one.
- Add the following to the end of the `.gitignore` file to prevent the `/uploads` directory from being tracked in source control:

  ```
  # Exclude /uploads directory
  uploads
  ```